# How do I make a UIBarButtonItem be a circle and behave like a UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, uitabbaritem

I have a tabbar and I want to add a UIButton (giant box) on top of the center. How do I make a UIBarButtonItem do this? I want layers, rounded borders, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can init it with a customView like this

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```